# Rendering edit on linux

Tags: premiere, video-editor, editing, windows, linux

I use Adobe Premiere for editing and rendering videos which is a windows based software and then I use ffmpeg for converting those video clips into different qualities.

As you may know rendering process can be done faster on a linux OS. Fortunately I've got a linux based server but the problem is for some reasons (I mean work related reasons and not technical) I can't do the editing job on linux which means I'm stuck on Premier or any other Windows based software like Edius,etc.

Is there any way to do the editing on windows (by Premier or Edius or other softwares) and do the rendering process on a linux OS?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Welcome M.Shahrokhi :) Maybe you want to start with the tour: http://video.stackexchange.com/tour to get your first bagde. Anyway, nice question - the only chance I see is using an **edl** and try to import it into one of linux nle's, see: http://video.stackexchange.com/questions/2274/good-open-source-video-editors or write a tool to use ffmpeg with it. Related: http://video.stackexchange.com/questions/14758/which-different-edl-types-exist. Enjoy video.se!

Comment: Thank you for your helpful comment, Now I was wondering If you could tell me how may I only render(not edite) a Premier edl expor in linux . In the other words what is the suitable package that can import and render Premier edl exports? Considering the fact that i want to implement the solution in ilinux server through command line.

Comment: Just an idea, unfortunately I can't give you specific instructions. I'd search for a tool that also runs headless and supports premiere edls **or** simply use ffmpeg (maybe there are some libraries, worklflows or solutions already) and give it a try... Note: You have to convert or export the edit. Rendering only, seems impossible without adobe linux support (running the app on linux). A Virtual Machine or Wine could be a solution too.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help ! now I have another question: May I use a render manager for rendering Adobe premier or even After Effetct projects on linux ? I mean all of those render managers support major platforms including linux but dose that mean they can render a After Effetct project on linux , Thanks again.

Comment: If it's another question - then please ask another question. Do you mean something like _Deadline_? Never tested, but I can't believe that's a cross platform solution for after effects, again unfortunately  adobe products are win or osx only.

Comment: Glad I could help - I'd be interested to know your final pipeline, keep us posted here :)

Comment: I am defienatly going to do that , I actually took your advice and asked it seprately :http://video.stackexchange.com/questions/15781/can-any-render-manager-render-premier-or-after-effect-on-linux   , Thaks again for your patience

Comment: I was wondering if you could take a look at this related question: http://video.stackexchange.com/questions/15791/frame-server-for-linuxubuntu

Comment: My apologize, I was so busy with the subject that I completely forgot about  that. Thank;s for the answer by the way.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic. You posted 2 copies of this question here, and one on AskUbuntu. You have accepted the AskUbuntu answer. Please don't cross post or post multiples.